# How to find similar named databases in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I need to find out if there any similar named databases in my DB setup - for example 'BusApp', 'BusApp2', 'BusAppTrial', etc.

I know that I can execute "show databases" command and check the output. 
But I need to check it from a shell file. 
Thus I am looking for some SQL like:

```
SELECT count(*) from information_schema.XXX where DBName like 'BusAp%'
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT table_schema
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema like 'BusAp%'
group by table_schema
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12c42/4)

Comment: He said databases, not tables. Although it's possible he's confused about the terminology.

Comment: I wanted to mean the "database" name - not the "table name" - so I think Barmar's SQL will work fine.

Comment: @javauser71: `table_schema` is the DB name.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*)
from information_schema.schemata
where schema_name like 'BusAp%'
```